# Post or upload file to specific user

Tags: files

I am new to Drupal, I wonder how can I post file(s) that should be viewable to specific user? for example upload a pdf invoice to a specified user? Thank you!

Comment: @JalilKhan Nope, permissions does not affect files, not on their own. Please be careful what you suggest.

Comment: @Bimmer, I have faced same question.So post detailed answer here please go through step by step. It is perfect answer of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send private message with file, use [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module. It used to have [issues with attachment privacy](https://www.drupal.org/node/956618), but it is Closed (fixed) - should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally permissions are configured per role, but, if you don't mind some PHP, you can extend the field permissions with [`hook_field_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7)

One suggestion would be to add the file field to the user entity itself at admin > config > account settings > manage fields (e.g field_pdf_invoice)

Then, you can attach the file to the user.

After that, something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_access
 */
function MODULE_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account){
  // Check view access to invoice field
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_pdf_invoice' && $op == 'view') {
    // Allow access if current user is viewing own account field
    if($entity_type == 'user' && $account->uid == $entity->uid){
      return TRUE;
    }elseif(user_access('administer users'){
      // Allow access to admins
      return TRUE;
    }
    // Default deny view.
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think for someone new to Drupal ready-made module may be a better option. Fun fact - personally I would rather go your way than mine.

Comment: Thanks :) I had a look at `field_permissions` module, but that's role based to OP may need some custom logic to target individual users - not sure if there's a module for that...

Comment: Take a look at my answer - privatemsg module allows attachments and ensures only recipient can download them. I don't know how *good* it is at the task, but it seems it covers everything OP wanted.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good option too, just came in as I was coding my answer :) assuming it can handle file attachments securely (private file mode?) looks like another solution!

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1: Install following modules and enable it.**

[Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)

[Chaos tool suite (ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)

[Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)

[Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

**Step 2 : Create Content Type:**

Here you can add extra field 
One for upload file and 
another for select user who can acess this file(Which is generated from user list of our site using entity reference module).

[image]
Please see:

Edit Field select user:
If you want to allow file to many users then choose Number of values : Unlimited (its give option to checkbox)
If you want to allow file to acess only one user then choose Number of values : 1.

[image]

**Step 3: Now Add content.**

[image]

**Step 4 : Create view.**

[image]

**Step 5 : User can only see files which is accessible/permission** 
[image]

Comment: So what will stop other users from opening this node directly (by guessing nid, for example) and accessing file? Also, please keep your screenshots under 630px width, to keep them readable.

Comment: @Molot, I have implemented test demo of drupal site to give proper answer.I am new to post answer here, but my aim to covered all details related to question so questioner can easily understand it.So I apologies for screenshot. Thanks for appreciate me.